# ¿Puedes ayudarme a entender esta Función de C?

Tags: c

Tengo entendido que esta función se usa para obtener el número de día del primer día de ese año, para que podamos imprimir la fecha en la posición correcta., Pero quisiera saber como trabaja internamente y llega a un resutado que siempre es Correcto!

```
int determinedaycode(int year)
{
int daycode;
int d1, d2, d3;

d1 = (year - 1.)/ 4.0;
d2 = (year - 1.)/ 100.;
d3 = (year - 1.)/ 400.;
daycode = (year + d1 - d2 + d3) %7;
return daycode;
}
```

Esta funcion hace parte de un generador de calendarios para cualquier año, dejare el link del codigo completo creado por CODINGUNIT.

https://www.codingunit.com/how-to-make-a-calendar-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero toma en cuenta que se usa el calendario gregoriano para poder hacer el programa. Después, considera los años bisiestos (que es en donde tienes dudas)

Comentaré el código para que se entienda lo antes se explicó.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Recibe un número entero como parámetro, en este caso el año
int determinedaycode(int year){
    //Declaración de variables
    int daycode, d1, d2, d3;
    
    /* Si el año ingresado es divisible por 4, entonces es un año bisiesto. 
    Pero si ese año es divisible por 100, entonces no es un año bisiesto. 
    Sin embargo, si el año también es divisible por 400, entonces es un 
    año bisiesto. */
    d1 = (year - 1)/ 4;
    d2 = (year - 1)/ 100;
    d3 = (year - 1)/ 400;
    
    //El resultado de la siguiente operación se divide entre los días de la semana
    return (year + d1 - d2 + d3) %7;
}

//Función principal del programa
int main(void){
    int year, daycode;
    
    //Variable con el año que se desea calcular en que día de la semana empezó el año
    year = 2020;
    daycode = determinedaycode(year);
    printf("El año empezó en el día %d", daycode);
}
```

Espero haber aclarado tu dudas, saludos.